# Difference between RemoveUntil and PopUntil in Flutter navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

1)What is the difference between RemoveUntil and PopUntil in Flutter navigator?

2)If have 3 screens A->B->C and now assuming i'm at Screen C and i perform popuntil Screen A,so will this pop Screen A as well or will it pop till Screen B and keep Screen A as it is?

Answer (score 0):

**pushAndRemoveUntil:**

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
    LoginScreen()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

This code will route to the login screen and pop all the screens which are in the back stack.

**popUntil:**

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/widget_name'));
```

This code will pop all the screens till the mentioned screen, here that screen name is `widget_name`